# Gradle plugin must not include version

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I have a multiproject gradle project

- project_android

  - project_lib
  - app

`project-lib` is in its own git repository which I added to to `project_android` using `git subtree`.

I'm stuck. In order to build `project_lib` by itself, I need to specify a version for this plugin. If I don't have the version

```
plugins {
  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
}
```

I get this error when building

````
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)
```
````

So I add a version and then it works

```
plugins {
  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version "1.7.10"
}
```

But now I can't build `project_android`, here is the error

```
Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.7.10']
> Plugin request for plugin already on the classpath must not include a version
```

I haven't added this plugin to `app` so I don't know where it comes from. This is the plugins in `project_android/app/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    // Kotlin Annotation Processing Tool
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    // Google Services plugin
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    // Navigation
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    // Performance Monitoring plugin
    id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
}
```

One project requires me to add a version. Another requires me not to add a version. What do I do to keep both happy?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by using the gradle legacy plugin dsl. In `project_lib\build.gradle` instead of:

```
plugins {
  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.17.10'
}
```

I instead do this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10"
    }
}

apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm"
```

Comment: `plugins {
  id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.7.10" apply false
}
`

Doesn't this work? We define the versions in our root `build.gradle` file and the versions are then passed to sub-projects.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I run into this it's because there is another implementation of that plug-in in one of the other gradle files.  Look in your build.gradle project file and/or your gradle settings file to see if another version of 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' is listed.  You may have to play around with deleting it from one of those other files and resyncing the gradle until it works.